# How do I return path to file if it exists in python

Tags: python, file-handling

I have to check that file exists or not, and if it does, have to return path to it , the main problem is that `os.path.isdir` returns only `True` or `False` depending on existence, so it seems it does not fit. Any hints? Current schema in my mind  is:

```
def get_config_path():
    if exists(path1):
        return path1
    if exists(path2):
        return path2
```

Comment: And where do `path1` and `path2` come from? If they are not defined in the function you should use parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke `os.stat(filename)`  where filename can be a file or directory path.  If the file exists, it will return a valid stat object. Otherwise, it throws a FileNotFound exception.